# Unable to create new users with Organic Groups module installed

Tags: organic-groups, wsod

I have Organic Groups version 7.x-2.9 installed on a Drupal 7.50 install.

When I try to add users from `/admin/people/create` I get a white screen and the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   EntityReference_SelectionHandler_Broken::buildEntityFieldQuery() in
>   /var/www/sandbox/sites/all/modules/contrib/og/plugins/entityreference/selection/OgSelectionHandler.class.php
>   on line 79, referer: http://drupal.sandbox/node/25

Does anybody know how I fix this? Otherwise I can't use [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module, I guess I'll have to try the Group module instead.

I found this issue on Drupal.org but there doesn't seem to be a fix for it

https://www.drupal.org/node/1796980

What is it about my site that might be causing this? Presumably there are 32,461 other Drupal sites running successfully with OG installed.

UPDATE - I subsequently installed the same version of OG on a different Drupal site where I am not seeing this problem, so it must be something weird about the first site.

Comment: If you have a choice, try the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module  ...